# Ruby Nokogiri RSpec - SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection - getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: ruby, sockets, rspec, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to scrape information from the One Piece anime wiki pages. I have written tests that check against past scrapes I have stored in `.txt` files, as wiki updates the information on their pages every few months or so.

All RSpec tests pass when I run them individually. Running **all** application RSpec tests at once fails all Scraper tests.

If I run all scraper tests by themselves:

```
Scraper
  instance methods
    #get_all_characters scrapes a list of characters
    #get_all_fruits scrapes a list of fruits
    #get_fruits_info scrapes devil fruit info
    #get_summary scrapes the show summary
    #get_haki scrapes Haki information
    #get_episode_list scrapes how many episodes there are

Finished in 6.04 seconds (files took 0.60889 seconds to load)
6 examples, 0 failures
```

All tests will pass. But if I run every test within the spec folder, all tests fail with the same error:

```
Scraper
  instance methods
    #get_all_characters scrapes a list of characters (FAILED - 1)
    #get_all_fruits scrapes a list of fruits (FAILED - 2)
    #get_fruits_info scrapes what devil fruits are (FAILED - 3)
    #get_summary scrapes the show summary (FAILED - 4)
    #get_haki scrapes information about Haki (FAILED - 5)
    #get_episode_list scrapes how many episodes there are (FAILED - 6)

Failures:

  1) Scraper instance methods #get_all_characters scrapes a list of characters
     Failure/Error: page = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(site))
 
     SocketError:
       Failed to open TCP connection to onepiece.fandom.comhttps:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:99:in `grab_bio'
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:106:in `block in all_character_bios'
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:105:in `each'
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:105:in `all_character_bios'
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:40:in `get_all_characters'
   # ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:6:in `initialize'
   # ./spec/cli/scraper_spec.rb:6:in `new'
   # ./spec/cli/scraper_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ------------------
   # --- Caused by: ---
   # SocketError:
   #   getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
   #   ./lib/classes/scraper.rb:99:in `grab_bio'
```

Why would running **all tests** *cause* the Socket Error? The Scraper spec test is the only one testing the Scraper class. No other spec tests instantiate an instance of the Scraper class. I can't seem to find out why this is happening.

Has anyone encountered this error before? Why does it happen?

**Scraper spec test repo link:** https://github.com/GoodGuyGuf/One_Piece/blob/main/spec/cli/scraper_spec.rb

**Project Repo:** https://github.com/GoodGuyGuf/One_Piece

**Scraper Spec Code:**

```
require_relative "../spec_helper.rb"
describe Scraper do

  before(:context) do
    SCRAPER = Scraper.new
  end

  context "instance methods" do
    it "#get_all_characters scrapes a list of characters" do
      all_characters_scrape = ScraperHelper.obj_to_arr_of_hashes(SCRAPER.characters)
      old_character_read = eval(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/characters.txt"))
      expect(all_characters_scrape).to eq(old_character_read)
    end

    it "#get_all_fruits scrapes a list of fruits" do
      all_fruits_scrape = ScraperHelper.obj_to_arr_of_hashes(SCRAPER.fruits)
      old_fruits_read = eval(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/fruits.txt"))
      expect(all_fruits_scrape).to eq(old_fruits_read)
    end

    it "#get_fruits_info scrapes what devil fruits are" do
      expect(SCRAPER.fruits_info).to match(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/fruits_info.txt"))
    end

    it "#get_summary scrapes the show summary" do
      expect(SCRAPER.summary).to match(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/summary.txt"))
    end

    it "#get_haki scrapes information about Haki" do
      expect(SCRAPER.haki).to match(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/haki.txt"))
    end

    it "#get_episode_list scrapes how many episodes there are" do
    expect(SCRAPER.episode_list).to match(ScraperHelper.read_file("./data/episodes.txt"))
    end 
  end
end
```

I'm not using `let` above as subsequent tests scrape information twice, creating double the amount of objects. By using `before(:context)`, the Scraper instance is set once ensuring all tests pass and will output the correct information.